# Hibernate Criteria API produces invalid SQL with aggregates when using orderBy()

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA in a project that uses Spring Data with Hibernate's Criteria API underneath. Using `JpaSpecificationExecutor` I was able to create queries that would let me use filtering and paging at the same time in my repository using a `Specification`, by just calling `Page<EventPost> findAll(Specification<EventPost> specification, Pageable pageable);` without a hitch.

The Problem that I have now, is that I can't order the results without hibernate generating invalid queries like this one:

`select count(eventpost0_.event_id) as col_0_0_ from event_post eventpost0_ where eventpost0_.category_event_category_id=? order by eventpost0_.createDate desc`

Apparently, Hibernate has to count the rows before it issues the real finder query, and erroneously adds the order by clause from my Criteria to the `select count(*)` statement.

This is verbatim what I see in the logs:

```
2016-09-05 09:22:36.987 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select count(eventpost0_.event_id) as col_0_0_ from event_post eventpost0_ where eventpost0_.category_event_category_id=? order by eventpost0_.createDate desc
2016-09-05 09:22:36.991 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] WARN  o.h.e.j.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42803
2016-09-05 09:22:36.992 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR o.h.e.j.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: column "eventpost0_.createdate" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
  Position: 133
```

And this is how I create my query

```
@Override
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<EventPost> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        Path<EventPost> category = root.get("category");
        Path<Long> participants = root.get("participants");
        Path<EventPostType> eventPostType = root.get("eventPostType");

        final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

        if(criteria.getEventCategory()!=null){
            predicates.add(cb.equal(category,criteria.getEventCategory()));
        }

        if(criteria.getParticipantsFrom()!=null){
            predicates.add(cb.ge(participants,criteria.getParticipantsFrom()));
        }else if(criteria.getParticipantsTo()!=null){
            predicates.add(cb.lt(participants,criteria.getParticipantsTo()));
        }

        if(criteria.getEventPostType()!=null){
            predicates.add(cb.equal(eventPostType,criteria.getEventPostType()));
        }

        query.orderBy(cb.desc(root.get("createDate")));

        return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
}
```

When I remove `query.orderBy(cb.desc(root.get("createDate")));` , everything works fine. Any Ideas what might be wrong here?

Versions are as follows:

```
PostgreSQL Database 9.5.3.0 with PostGIS
spring-orm:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE
spring-data-jpa:jar:1.9.4.RELEASE
hibernate-spatial:jar:4.3:compile
hibernate-core:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile
postgresql:jar:8.4-701.jdbc4:compile
postgis-jdbc:jar:1.5.2:compile
```

Comment: You are returning one column and one row `count` - how would you like this ordered?

Comment: I do not really need the row count myself. I assume the count is generated by hibernate itself for internal reasons, no? I would like to have the results of all my predicates ordered by createDate.

Comment: Is something being set outside of this method?

Comment: Nothing that involves the data layer. It's all encapsulated in the Specification really.

Comment: @keyboardsamurai ur assumption is most probably wrong.

Comment: well it does not seem to be set within this method.

Comment: @Antoniossss - well, thinking about it, it is more likely that spring-data generates the count because it needs the total number of rows for the Page object

Comment: @keyboardsamurai if you got some sort of pagination involved in your action etc, then yes it is possible. In this single piece of code u provided, hibernate doesnt care about result set plausible size. Iv been using JPA for some time with Hibernate under the hood and never had such autogenerated counts.

Comment: You shouldn't be ordering in your specification. You are invoking a method that contains a `Pagable` that object also holds the ordering information. You should pass the ordering using that object not do it yourself.

Comment: m-deinum: You are right. It seems that adding sorting information in the Specification seems to confuse spring-data. Adding @SortDefault to my Controller's Pageable object solved the problem immediately. Care to post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it as correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
I have the following code which worked for me 

CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<T> cq = cb.createQuery(entity);
    Root<T> root = cq.from(entity);

 cq.orderBy(cb.desc(cb.sum(root.get(orderByString))));

// orderByString is string entity field that is being aggregated and which we want to put in orderby clause as well.
```